# The best way to display repeated data in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have an ASP.Net web page that displays various chunks of data based on a user's search string. In this web page I'm using a `<Panel>` tag because I need to have a vertical scrollbar that displays when needed to display all of the data.

I've thought about defining an HTML page (in code behind, with all the tags and data included), and displaying that inside a `<div>`, inside the `<Panel>`.

I've also explored the possibility of displaying an ASP.Net web page with the data/tags/etc. and placing each page in its own `<Iframe>` element. I'm afraid that this solution would be slow to load (as compaired to the HTML method described above) especially when there's 100's of individual pages to be loaded.

My question is what's the best way to display N number of individual pages of data and have a vertical scrollbar when there's a need?

Answer (score 0):

Displaying various data pieces on ASP.NET pages is a big subject, I suppose, and many methods can be used, including the ones you've mentioned.

How about making use of Dynamic Data framework .NET v2,3,4. The most powerful is the latest one of course.

Then you don't need to create 100's of individual pages, just onthe fly redirect using metatable names used in your model/context. All you data will also be wonderfully linked where appropriate. Also need to carefully design you model based on however your data needs be presented. The controls for that could be GridView or other, but all done on server side.

Comment: Dynamic Data Framework. Sounds good, but I never heard of it till now! It looks like I have some studying to do.... :-) Thanks!